# Error in Xamarin.Forms Release with Lottie/CacheStrategy

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am getting an error, when I try to deploy my android apk  xamarin forms or when I compile release. it has to do with the library lottie  cachestrategy
        error  follows.

> Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void >XF.Material.Droid.Renderers.MaterialCircularLoadingViewRenderer::OnElementChanged>(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs`1)' in assembly: 'XF.Material.Droid.dll' ---> >Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve Com.Airbnb.Lottie.LottieAnimationView/CacheStrategy >Com.Airbnb.Lottie.LottieAnimationView/CacheStrategy::get_Strong()
>     en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod(MethodReference reference)
>     en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
>     en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
>     en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
>     en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
>     en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
>     --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
>     en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
>     en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
>     en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
>     en MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
>     en Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
>     en MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
>     en Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
>     en Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
>     en Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>     en Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()    Amis.Reportes.Android
>
> and option Linking is "Link SDK assemblies only"

Comment: Paste the text not picture, its impossible to read

Comment: What did you set as linking option in Android options?

Comment: Link SDK assemblies only